# How to give continuous indexing for consecutive ng-repeat elements in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, indexing

I am creating some div elements using multiple ng-repeat. Number of ng-repeat elements are dynamic.I want to give continuous indexing for all elements.How is it done in angular way?

like

```
<div ng-repeat="item in [1,2,1,5]">{{$index+1}}_{{item}}</div>
<div ng-repeat="item in [5,2]">{{$index+1}}_{{item}}</div>
<div ng-repeat="item in [4,6]">{{$index+1}}_{{item}}</div>
```

Expected result

```
<div>1_1</div> 
<div>2_2</div> 
<div>3_1</div> 
<div>4_5</div> 
<div>5_5</div>
<div>6_2</div>
<div>7_4</div>
<div>8_6</div>
```

Comment: why not concat your arrays and do only one ng-repeat ?

Comment: or use ordered list of HTML

Comment: @Alexandre Divs are at different places. And added to the pages on different events.

Comment: @FreddyPv ok, maybe you can use length of each array ?

<div ng-repeat="item in array1">{{$index+1}}_{{item}}</div>
<div ng-repeat="item in array2">{{array1.length+$index+1}}_{{item}}</div>

Comment: @binariedMe Cannot use ordered list. Actually there are more content in div

Comment: @Alexandre But number of arrays are dynamic. And array names.

Comment: Can you give give us plunker or example of your code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work although it is dodgy. 'profile' is used to represent an object to avoid isolated scope. You can write the directive with this logic.

```
<span ng-init="profile.count = 0">{{profile.count}}</span>
<div ng-repeat="item in [1,2,1,5] track by $index" 
     ng-init="count=profile.count+1;profile.count=profile.count+1">{{::count}}_{{item}}</div>
<div ng-repeat="item in [5,2] track by $index" 
     ng-init="count=profile.count+1;profile.count=profile.count+1">{{::count}}_{{item}}</div>
<div ng-repeat="item in [4,6] track by $index" 
     ng-init="count=profile.count +1;profile.count=profile.count+1">{{::count}}_{{item}}</div>
```